# Dynamically align Header and Paragraph from text blocks on a webpage

Tags: html, css

I have a webpage designed based on Grid and Flexbox.

One of the sections of the page is a "features" container in which two articles (class= "feature") are displayed.
On screen widths up to 768px these two articles are displayed below eachother in a column.
CSS:

```
.features {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat 1fr;
    gap: 2vh;
}

.feature {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow:column;
}
```

in my media query for screen widths between 768px and 1024px the css makes sure that the articles are displayed next to eachother.
CSS:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1023px) {
    .features {
        grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    }
```

Now... each article has a header and one paragraph of rougly 100 words, but the headers and paragraphs are slighlty different in length for each article.

When I check my page in the inspector now and increase the screenwidth, the increasing witdh of the containers creates inconsistancies in alignment. At certain screen widths, the header of one article is on two lines and the other on one, which misaligns the paragraphs below.
Plus, because the paragraphs themselves are not equally long, a different screen width might lead to one paragraph to be (i.e) on 10 lines and the other on 9 lines.

I don't mind that the headers are sometimes on three, on two or on one line,
but regardless of that, I want my paragraphs always to start on the same vh when the articles are displayed side by side and that if one paragraph uses more lines than the other on a certain screenwidth, that the containers of both articles are equal in height and the paragraphs starting on the same height.

How do I manage that?

My html is:

```
<section class="content-area">
            <section class="features">
                <article class="feature">
                    <h2>Ontdek Oostenrijk & de Alpen</h2>
                    <p>Droom weg bij de gedachte aan een gezinsvakantie in Oostenrijk en de majestueuze Alpen. Waar zomerse valleien en winterse skipistes het decor vormen voor eindeloos avontuur en natuur. Onze blog onthult de mooiste plekjes en biedt essentiële tips voor een onvergetelijke reis. Laat je inspireren door de ongerepte natuur en beleef de Alpen op zijn best.</p>
                </article>
                <article class="feature">
                    <h2>Avontuur in de Dolomieten & Noord-Italië</h2>
                    <p>Laat je gezin kennismaken met de mix van avontuur en cultuur in Noord-Italië en de Dolomieten. Ontdek wandelparadijzen, wereldklasse ski-gebieden en de betoverende kanalen van Venetië. Onze blog gidst je door adembenemende landschappen en historische steden, vol tips voor een onvergetelijke vakantie. Ontdek samen de schoonheid van Italië.</p>
                </article>
            </section>
</section>
```

I tried many different things already, but kinda lost myself in all the failed attempts.
Can someone point me in the right direction please?

```css
.features {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat 1fr;
    gap: 2vh;
}

.feature {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow:column;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1023px) {
    .features {
        grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    }
}
```

```html
<section class="content-area">
            <section class="features">
                <article class="feature">
                    <h2>Ontdek Oostenrijk & de Alpen</h2>
                    <p>Droom weg bij de gedachte aan een gezinsvakantie in Oostenrijk en de majestueuze Alpen. Waar zomerse valleien en winterse skipistes het decor vormen voor eindeloos avontuur en natuur. Onze blog onthult de mooiste plekjes en biedt essentiële tips voor een onvergetelijke reis. Laat je inspireren door de ongerepte natuur en beleef de Alpen op zijn best.</p>
                </article>
                <article class="feature">
                    <h2>Avontuur in de Dolomieten & Noord-Italië</h2>
                    <p>Laat je gezin kennismaken met de mix van avontuur en cultuur in Noord-Italië en de Dolomieten. Ontdek wandelparadijzen, wereldklasse ski-gebieden en de betoverende kanalen van Venetië. Onze blog gidst je door adembenemende landschappen en historische steden, vol tips voor een onvergetelijke vakantie. Ontdek samen de schoonheid van Italië.</p>
                </article>
            </section>
</section>
```